# Grep the first number in a line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file that has lines of numbers and a file:

```
    2    20    3    file1.txt
    93   21    42   file2.txt
    52   10    12   file3.txt
```

How do I use grep, awk, or some other command to just give me the first numbers of each line so that it will only display:

```
2
93
52
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So many ways to do this.  Here are some (assuming the input file is `gash.txt`):

```
awk '{print $1}' gash.txt
```

or using pure bash:

```
while read num rest
do
    echo $num
done < gash.txt
```

or using "classic" `sed`:

```
sed 's/[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' gash.txt
```

or using ERE with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[ \t]*([0-9]+).*/\1/' gash.txt
```

Using `cut` is problematic because we don't know if the whitespace is spaces or tabs.

By the way,  if you want to add the total number of lines:

```
awk '{total+=$1} END{print "Total:",total}' gash.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, you read my mind with the total :)

Comment: Also, note that if you pass multiple files to `wc`, it will print total by default.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me! My text is stored in a variable so to run the command on it I did: `awk '{print $1}' <<< "$variable_string"`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' filename
```

To handle the leading spaces, I'm currently out of options. You better accept the awk answer.

Comment: You don't need the first set of `[ ]` for a single space (although it does aid readability), but it might be better to consider `[ \t]*`, or `\s*` since we don't know the file format.

Comment: @cdarke : thanks, I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Thats fine, I just wanted the numbers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```